# Does this derivative have a name?

Tags: derivatives, terminology

What is this derivative called:
$$
D_\gamma f = \lim_{dt\to 0} \frac{f(\gamma(dt))-f(\gamma(0))}{||\gamma(dt)-\gamma(0)||}
$$
It is not the same as the directional derivative or the Gateux derivative on wikipedia. Perhaps it is not as general since it uses a vector norm. (or perhaps it is but I don't see it)

Comment: Is there some reason you are interested in this derivative?  That limit will very rarely exist...

Comment: Are there hypothesis on $\gamma$ ?

Comment: (Notice, for instance, that if $\gamma(t)=t$, then $D_\gamma f$ will not exist for any ordinarily differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(0)\neq 0$.)

Comment: @EricWofsey: Can you explain? For me, $\gamma(t) = t$ results in $D_\gamma f = \lim_{h\searrow0}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h - 0} = f'(0)$.

Comment: Notice the norm at the denominator. @gerw

Comment: @nicomezi: I think I know what you mean. However, I interpreted $dt \to 0$ as $dt \searrow 0$, e.g., $dt > 0$, and I think this is what the OP had in mind.

Comment: I am interested in it because it was fairly stable and accurate when I had to create a derivative/jacobian without knowing it for a numerical analysis toy program I am making. You can change the limit if you think it is wrong, I don't know how to make the downrightarrow .

Comment: Even if $dt$ has to be positive, there is missing information about $\gamma$.  @gerw Could you clarify the situation OP ?

Comment: @nicomezi: not really, I just wanted to see if something that looks like this derivative has a name since I liked the intuition behind it. \gamma is vector valued. I was thinking perhaps it can be used to emulate curves in differential geometry.

Comment: Then gerw's answer is what you are looking for, I guess.

Comment: I meant tangent space elements not curves.

Answer (score 5):

In the case that $\gamma$ is differentiable at $0$, this is very similar to the definition of the Hadamard derivative. There, the existence of
$$\frac{f(\bar x + t_n \, h_n) - f(\bar x)}{t_n}$$
is required for all sequences $t_n \searrow 0$ and $h_n \to h$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_derivative.